# Grails: Controller unit test, what should the action's responsibility be?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, controller

In the example https://guides.grails.org/grails-controller-testing/guide/index.html, a valid payload is required for the success case, but this should not be a requirement, the test should only be to validate what the action should actually do?

Example:

```
class OneController {

    def list(OneCommand command) {

        if (command.hasErrors()) {

            render command.errors as JSON
            return
        }

        respond oneService.save(command.param1) as JSON
    }
}
```

If command is valid, you must call Stub(oneService.save()) passing command.param1 as parameter and the return must be the return of this service as JSON.

If command is invalid, it should return command.errors as JSON.

And in another unit test, test OneCommand.

Answer (score 0):

> In the example
> https://guides.grails.org/grails-controller-testing/guide/index.html,
> a valid payload is required for the success case, but this should not
> be a requirement, the test should only be to validate what the action
> should actually do?

Supplying a valid payload is not the only way to test this, but it is a common way.

There are 2 paths through the code being tested.  One path is triggered if `command.hasErrors()` evaluates to `true` and the other path is triggered if `command.hasErrors()` does not evaluate to `true`.  Tests should cover each of those paths.  Supplying a test with a valid payload and a test with an invalid payload is a simple way to accomplish that.  There are other ways, for example one could invoke the `list` method on the controller and pass a mocked `OneCommand` as a parameter.